# Jquery call angular's function then call $apply() always get Error:[$rootScope:inprog]

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I use ng-repeat to generate the directive-a,and in the directive-a's template also use ng-repeat to generate the directive-subA.

I know when I use the jquery to invoke the angular's function,I must to call $apply() to raise the digest cycle.

But when I call the $apply() in my console it have error message:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]...

But the result is correct.

If I comment the $apply() call code,the error is not show but the result is not what I want.

Help me ,plz.

Here is my data structure:

```
tyep:{
    id:'XXX',
    name:'XXX'
}
product:{
    id:'XXX',
    name:'XXX'
}

specs:[type1,type2,type3]
products:[A,B,C]
```

View

```
<div ng-controller="testController">        
    <test class="test" ng-repeat="spec in specs" 
        spec="spec" products="products"></test>
</div>
```

directive:test

```
{
    restirct:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
        spec:'=',
        products:'='
    },
    template:
        <div>
            {{spec.name}}
            <sub-test product="product" 
                ng-repeat="product in products">
            </sub-test>
        </div>,
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){}
}
```

directive:subTest

```
{
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
        product:'='
    },
    template:
        <div>{{product.name}}</div>,
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){}
}
```

controller:testController

```
$scope.products={};
$scope.specs={};
$scope.set=function(products,specs){
    this.products=products;
    this.specs=specs;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
    specs:[type1,type2,type3];
    products:[productA,productB,productC];
    angular.element($('.test')).scope().set(specs,products);
    angular.element($('.test')).scope().$apply();
})
```

Comment: I believe this error is because already a digest cycle is in progress when you are doing $apply(). Try to give a `timeout` for your `$apply()` and see..But why do you need to use `jquery` for this since `products` and `specs` are already on scope.. `ng-repeat` will automatically detect them

Comment: Btw, Aren't `$scope.products={};` `$scope.specs={};` these supposed to be an arrays?

Comment: The `<a>` tag is reserved for anchor tags. Is it your intention to turn all anchor tags in your HTML into an element directive with isolate scope? For more information, see [MDN Element Reference `<a>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: I just wanna be simple,I edit <a> to <test>,<sub-a> to <sub-test>

Comment: Here is the situation,I have a jquery slider and an angular detail panel when I click the slider R/L button,I want the angular part dynamically display the info of slider's items.

Comment: I thought the model is an object or an array are doesn't matter.I just wanna detect when the change was happened and then the directives will use the new version value to work.And I wrong?

Comment: Though I don't know why ,but wrap the $apply() into the setTimeout the problem is solved,thank you! @Ravi Teja

Comment: Reason is by the time you are explicitly calling `$apply()` there is already an `$apply()`(digest cycle) is in progress(trigerred by AngularJS).. so, if you wrap `$apply()` in `setTimeout` your `$apply()` will get executed in the `next` `digest cycle`. So, there will be no conflict.